# Create calculator in React from preexisting template

Tags: reactjs

I need to Create a webpage with a textbox and a button. Enter any mathematical expression on the textbox and click the button, the result of the expression will be shown in an alert window. For example, enter 2+3-1 and click the button. It should show 4 in the alert window. I need to use ReactJS to create the webpage.

```
import React from 'react';
class Addition extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
        num1:'',
        num2:'',
        total:''
        }
    }

    handlenum1 = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            num1:event.target.value
        })

    }

    handlenum2 = (event) =>{
        this.setState({
            num2:event.target.value
        })

    }
    exe = (event) => {
        this.setState({total:parseInt(this.state.num1) + 
parseInt(this.state.num2)});
        event.prevent.default();

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <h1> Addition </h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.exe}>
            <div>
            Number 01:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.num1} onChange={this.handlenum1}/>
            </div>
            <div>
            Number 02:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.num2} onChange={this.handlenum2}/>
            </div>
            <div>
            <button type= "submit"> Add </button>
            </div>
            </form>
            {this.state.total}
            </div>

        )
    }

}
export default Addition;
```

Comment: Please be sure to add any steps you have tried and any issues you are coming across. Many people will not outright solve this for you, but would rather help lead you in the correct direction to the solution. Best of luck.

Comment: Can i see what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://youtu.be/y_CBbq2vWiQ

Comment: i refered the above link

Answer (score 0):

> Make this changes in your onClick event **exe**

```
 exe = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        total: parseInt(this.state.num1) + parseInt(this.state.num2),
      },
      () => {
        alert(this.state.total);
      }
    );
  };
```

> **setState** accepts a callback as its second argument, it makes **setState** synchronous in nature.

If you want to know more about **setstate**, Then refer this https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

> And you wrote `event.prevent.default();` in your "onClick event **exe**", I'm afraid it is `event.preventDefault();`

For more information  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: You want to show the result in the alert box, right?

Comment: but one text box only, and should b compatible for any operation like ive explained